# Cannot resolve symbol for facebook imports

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, gradle

Cannot resolve symbol for below facebook imports.

```
    import com.facebook.Request;
        import com.facebook.Response;
        import com.facebook.Session;
        import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter;
```

These are the gradle dependencies I am using

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parseui-login-android:0.0.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.4@aar'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
```

Answer (score 7):

avoid using version of dependencies like this 4.+, try set `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.2'`

Comment: It happens also if one has     compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
Changing to 4.8.2 solved it too